# Regex isn't being matched

Tags: java, regex

This is the code:

```
String newtask = "newTask[\\{] taskId\"(?<id>\\d{1,4})\", username\"\\w([_\\w\\d&&^(bahmanBAHMAN)]){6,15}\\d\", isValid\"(?<isitthough>(no|yes))\", name\"[\\w\\s]*\", address\"(?<address>[\\w\\s]+[-]\\d{8,10})\", date\"(?<date>\\d{8})\", info\"(?<info>[^\"]*)\", price\"(?<price>\\d+\\.{0,1}\\d*)\" "; String changeaddress = "changePlace[\\{] taskId\"(?<idtobechanged>\\d{1,4})\", newAddress\"(?<theaddress>[\\w\\s]+[-]\\d{8,10})\" ";
Pattern addingpat = Pattern.compile(newtask);
String command=scanner.nextLine();
Matcher addingmat = addingpat.matcher(command);
if (addingmat.find())
System.out.println("it has matched");
```

And what the user will type in terminal:

```
newTask{ taskId"1", username"AyesItsGoood4", isValid"yes", name"reza", address"LeninGrad-12345678", date"19410908", info"do the task", price"1.57"
```

It isn't printing anything.
I would be really thankful if somone pointed out the problem of this code.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What does `[_\\w\\d&&^(bahmanBAHMAN)]` mean in this pattern? Why not use `\\w` instead?

Comment: The letters in the username shouldn't be "bahman" or "BAHMAN" It's a regex university homework by the way so that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex needs to be fixed where you tried to use character class subtraction:

```
newTask[\{] taskId\"(?<id>\d{1,4})\", username\"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&&[^bahmnBAHMN]]{6,15}\d\", isValid\"(?<isitthough>no|yes)\", name\"[\w\s]*\", address\"(?<address>[\w\s]+-\d{8,10})\", date\"(?<date>\d{8})\", info\"(?<info>[^\"]*)\", price\"(?<price>\d+\.?\d*)\"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNtah9/1).

The `\w([_\w\d&&^(bahmanBAHMAN)]){6,15}\d\"` is replaced with `(?!(?i:bahman\"))\w{7,16}\d\"`. Here is why:

- `\w([_\w\d&&^(bahmanBAHMAN)]){6,15}\d` - matches a word char (with `\w`), then 6-15 occurrences a `b`, `a`, `h`, `m`, `n`, `B`, `A`, `H`, `M`, `N` char, and then a digit. This happens because what you used is a [character class intersection](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html), and the `[_\w\d&&^(bahmanBAHMAN)]` pattern matches only those chars that are present both in the `[_\w\d]` and `[^(bahmanBAHMAN)]` charsets.
- The `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&&[^bahmnBAHMN]]{6,15}\d` pattern matches a single ASCII letter, then 6 to 15 ASCII letters other than `b`, `a`, `h`, `m` and `n` (case insensitive) and then a digit.

In Java:

```java
String newtask = "newTask\\{ taskId\"(?<id>\\d{1,4})\", username\"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&&[^bahmnBAHMN]]{6,15}\\d\", isValid\"(?<isitthough>no|yes)\", name\"[\\w\\s]*\", address\"(?<address>[\\w\\s]+-\\d{8,10})\", date\"(?<date>\\d{8})\", info\"(?<info>[^\"]*)\", price\"(?<price>\\d+\\.?\\d*)\"";
```